# Multiple Loops Inside a Function

Tags: wp-query, functions, loop

What I understand from the CODEX,  (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Multiple_Loops).

then I'm trying to do a list of posts like this:

```
<nav id="cbp-hrmenu" class="cbp-hrmenu main-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="#">Secciones</a>
              <div class="cbp-hrsub">
                <div class="cbp-hrsub-inner">
                  <div>
                    <h4><a href="#" class="menu-section">Topic 1</a></h4>
                    <ul>
                      <?php echo get_posts_menus('topic-1','3'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <h4><a href="#" class="menu-section">Topic 2</a></h4>
                    <ul>
                      <?php echo get_posts_menus('topic-2','3'); ?>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <h4><a href="#" class="menu-section">Topic 3</a></h4>
                    <ul>
                      <?php echo get_posts_menus('topic-3','3'); ?>
                    </ul>
                    <h4><a href="#" class="menu-section">Topic 4</a></h4>
                    <ul>
                      <?php echo get_posts_menus('topic-4','3'); ?>
                    </ul>

                  </div>
</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

If you notice , I'm calling a function named `get_posts_menus()` .

Where the function I'm using is:

```
if (!function_exists('get_posts_menus')):
  function get_posts_menus($category_name, $count)
{
  $permalink = get_the_permalink();
  $title     = get_the_title($the_menu->post->ID);
  $post_class = get_the_id();

  $args = array(
    'category_name' => $category_name,
    'posts_per_page' => $count
    );

  $the_menu = new WP_Query($args);

  while ($the_menu->have_posts()) {
    $the_menu->the_post();
    echo "<li class=\"post-id-$post_class\"><a href=\"$permalink\" alt=\"$title\">$title</a></li>";
  }
    wp_reset_postdata();

  }
  endif;
```

What happened here , is that it will give us back only the last post 3 times.

But the main idea is that this give back the 3 latest post of the category.

I'm very confused about this , that I'm start thinking of using JSON instead of the wp_query.

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the permalink and post title won't be available until after you've run the query. the following should return the last 3 posts from the designated category.

the same post is being displayed 3 times because it doesn't look like you're setting the permalink or post title from within "the loop"

```
if (!function_exists('get_posts_menus')):
  function get_posts_menus($category_name, $count)
{

  $args = array(
    'category_name' => $category_name,
    'posts_per_page' => $count
    );

  $the_menu = new WP_Query($args);

  while ($the_menu->have_posts()) {
    $post_class = get_the_id();
    $permalink = get_the_permalink();
    $title     = get_the_title();
    $the_menu->the_post();
    echo "<li class=\"post-id-$post_class\"><a href=\"$permalink\" alt=\"$title\">$title</a></li>";
  }
    wp_reset_postdata();

  }
  endif;
```